# Large Scale Quadratic Form with Linear Box Constraints

Tags: optimization, convex-optimization, numerical-optimization, quadratic-programming

I have the following quadratic program

$$\min_x x^TAx \qquad  \text{s.t} \quad Ax \in [a,b]^m$$

where matrix $A$ is positive semidefinite, and is similar both the objective function and in the constraint. I would like to solve this problem for large-scale input matrix $A$ and am looking for a swift solution.

Is there any specific recommendation from different optimization methods such as projection gradient, proximal gradient, trust region active set, so forth? Any comparison between these methods (and others) are appreciated.

Comment: Since $Ax$ is a vector, what do you mean by $Ax \in [a,b]$?

Comment: How large is $A$? Is it sparse or does it have any other structure?

Comment: That is right, Ax is vector! I edited the question.

Comment: The only thing we know is that A is positive semi definite! Nothing more is available

Comment: What is "large scale"? Do you have A explicitly? Try the L-BFGS-B algorithm.

Comment: @LinAlg I don't have much experience with L-BFGS, is L-BFGS-B able to handle the hard constraint that $Ax \in [a,b]^m$? I've read that it can handle box constraints like $x \in [a,b]^n$, but $Ax \in [a,b]^m$ is more difficult.

Comment: @littleO you are right. IPOPT with the limited-memory feature is a suitable alternative.

Answer (score 2):

One option which I think is promising is to formulate your problem as minimizing $f(x) + g(x) + h(Ax)$, where $f(x) = x^T A x$ and $g(x) = 0$ and $h(y) = I_{[a,b]}(y)$. (That is, $h$ is the convex indicator function of the set  denoted here as $[a,b]$.) The function $f$ is differentiable and $g$ and $h$ have easy proximal operators, so you can solve this optimization problem using the PD3O method (which is a recent three-operator splitting method).

In this approach, we never have to solve a linear system involving $A$, which is nice because $A$ is large.

Comment: Thanks for response! I have seen some three operator method using different proximal gradient! Can you a bit  explain the method?

Comment: An alternative (Which I find to be more clear than PD3O) is [A Three Operator Splitting Scheme and its Optimization Applications](https://arxiv.org/abs/1504.01032). Specifically see Algorithm 5 and Algorithm 8.

Comment: In your referred algorithm, [PD3O - A New Primal Dual Algorithm for Minimizing the Sum of Three Functions with a Linear Operator](https://arxiv.org/abs/1611.09805), the case for $ g = 0 $ is basically PAPC: https://imgur.com/a/yGd0jb2. This, an all variations of this algorithm, require the conjugate of the indicator function. How better is it compared to different approaches? For instance, Projected Gradient Descent won't require inversion as well.

Comment: @Royi The Davis-Yin method (Alg. 1 in the paper you linked to) minimizes $f(x) + g(x) + h(x)$, where $f$ is smooth and $g$ and $h$ are simple (that is, they have easy proximal operators). The PD30 method minimizes $f(x) + g(x) + h(Ax)$, and I’m making use of this additional flexibility in my approach to handle the constraint $Ax \in [a,b]^m$. Algorithm 5 in the Davis-Yin paper has the linear operator included in the differentiable term, which doesn’t help us handle the constraint $Ax \in [a,b]^m$.

Comment: PD30 can be derived from the Davis-Yin method, just as Chambolle-Pock can be derived from Douglas-Rachford. This is shown in paper “[On the Equivalence of the Primal-Dual Hybrid Gradient Method and Douglas-Rachford Splitting](https://scholar.google.com/citations?view_op=view_citation&hl=en&user=gK_sUR8AAAAJ&citation_for_view=gK_sUR8AAAAJ:hFOr9nPyWt4C)” with Vandenberghe.  This paper gives a clear presentation of PD30.

Comment: We can always use the Moreau identity to evaluate the proximal operator of the conjugate of a convex function $g$. So if we’re able to evaluate the proximal operator of $g$ efficiently, then we can easily evaluate the proximal operator of $g^*$ equally efficiently.

Comment: It’s not clear to me how to handle the constraint $Ax \in [a,b]^m$ using projected gradient descent, since projecting onto the constraint set isn’t easy.

Comment: @littleO. I agree. Yet, I implemented PD3O and it is very slow for this case. It is really hard to tweak the parameters. Don't you think Chambolle Pock will be enough here?

Comment: @Royi That's interesting that you tried PD30 here. I haven't actually tried it. Chambolle-Pock minimizes $g(x) + h(Ax)$ where $g$ and $h$ are simple (easy proximal operators), so to use Chambolle-Pock in this case we could take $h$ to be the indicator function of $[a,b]^m$ and $g(x) = x^T A x$. To evaluate the proximal operator of $g$ we would need to solve a linear system involving $A$, which might be expensive. So, I don't see how to use Chambolle-Pock here without needing to solve a linear system.

Comment: @littleO, Indeed. I implemented ADMM, Chamoblle Pock and PD3O. I think the methods which use the dual (CP, PD3O) struggles because of the indicator function. Could it be it doesn't obey the necessary conditions? I found this remark https://i.imgur.com/cxFGo7x.png on ۟[Antonin Chambolle, Thomas Pock - An introduction to continuous optimization for imaging](https://doi.org/10.1017/S096249291600009X) page 177 (17 in the PDF). Clearly indicator functions don't hold it. Yet in their paper they don't mention it. So I am not sure.

Comment: @littleO, When I mean don't hold it, I mean in the above where $ 0 \notin \left[ a, b \right] $. In that case the assumption the function is finite doesn't hold.

Comment: @littleO, Of course later those requirements are relaxed. But I wonder if those are what make the methods struggle with this, allegedly, simple case.

Comment: @littleO, I posted the code/ You may have a look.

Comment: That's interesting. The Chambolle-Pock stepsize restriction is $\sigma \tau \| A \|^2 \leq 1$. It looks like you're choosing $\sigma = \tau = 1 / \| A \|$. But for ADMM, I guess the step size value has been tuned somewhat. Chambolle-Pock will benefit greatly from tuning the value of $\tau$ by trial and error and taking $\sigma = 1/(\tau \| A \|^2)$. If we tune the step size for ADMM we should also tune the step size for Chambolle-Pock. (Apologies if I'm misunderstanding your experiment.)

Comment: @littleO, I didn't tweak $\rho$. I didn't optimize any of them. Just played for experimentation with Chambolle and PD3O and saw they are highly sensitive to the parameters (They have more as well). From my experience, ADMM is fairly robust. At least much more than the other 2.

Comment: Hmm, I can definitely believe from my own experience that the performance of Chambolle-Pock is highly sensitive to the values of $\sigma$ and $\tau$. In my experience Chambolle-Pock usually performs terribly if we choose $\sigma = \tau = 1/\| A \|$. It’s interesting to see your comparison here.

Comment: @littleO, Have you encountered any case where you'd prefer Chambolle Pock over ADMM?

Comment: @Royi Throughout my PhD I was often trying out splitting methods using Douglas-Rachford / ADMM in a clever way to make the linear system something that we can solve efficiently at each iteration. And I repeatedly found that when I did a fair comparison to Chambolle-Pock, tuning the step sizes and other parameters (like overrelaxation) for both methods, the victory over Chambolle-Pock was never as decisive as I had hoped. The Douglas-Rachford approach might be like twice as fast in my experiments but not like 10x as fast.

Comment: This experience was part of what led up to Vandenberghe‘s discovery that Chambolle-Pock is actually a special case of Douglas-Rachford, by the way. Or in other words that Chambolle-Pock can be derived from Douglas-Rachford, as shown in the “On the equivalence…” paper.

Comment: I could believe that some skillful users of ADMM are getting a more decisive victory over Chambolle-Pock, maybe by using a good preconditioning strategy and good adaptive step size selection strategy (as in Boyd’s POGS paper, perhaps).

Comment: In some radiation treatment planning problems that I’ve worked on, the dose-calculation matrix is so large that using Douglas-Rachford / ADMM seems not possible, because solving the relevant linear system seems too difficult. In such cases I have often thought that Chambolle-Pock is a preferable method to use.

Comment: @littleO, I guess they are pretty close in the case of tweaked constant parameters. I just find that ADMM doesn't require too much tweaking. Also I don't know methods to tweak priori to the actual run. Namely, given the functions, will you be able to extract optimal values without actually running the algorithm few times? ADMM with some simple adaptations of $\rho$ is really fast from what I've experienced.

Comment: I could believe that ADMM tends to require less step size or parameter tuning than Chambolle-Pock. In my experiments I usually laboriously tuned the parameters for both methods, so I don’t have a great feeling for what happens when trying to use these methods without much parameter tuning.

Comment: Out of curiosity, what simple adaptations for $\rho$ do you have in mind? It might be something I’m not aware of or something I haven’t experimented with.

Comment: @littleO, There are nice things at https://github.com/qpsolvers/qpsolvers. Tough I think they mostly comply with previous work of Boyd's team. By the way, unless you `@Royi` I don't get a notification about your comments.

Answer (score 2):

If you can afford a single calculation of the Eigen Decomposition of $ \boldsymbol{A} $ I'd go with ADMM.
Once you have the eigen decomposition you can solve the iterative problem by matrix multiplication only.

If you can't, you have 2 options:

1. Solve the Linear Equation with iterative solver (Conjugate Gradient). Probably even few iteration will be enough. Starting from the last solution (Warm up start) will probably make things pretty fast after few iterations.
2. Use Primal Dual methods to apply the indicator function on an auxiliary vector variable (Dual) instead of the matrix. You may use the method in @littleO answer ([PD3O - A New Primal Dual Algorithm for Minimizing the Sum of Three Functions with a Linear Operator](https://arxiv.org/abs/1611.09805)). There are others as well. Since you have 2 functions in the form $ \boldsymbol{A} \boldsymbol{x} $ then a 3 operators method is required.

#### ADMM Solution

Assuming one can apply some factorization (Eigen / SVD) on $ \boldsymbol{A} $ then this becomes the best solution.

The model:

$$\begin{align*}
\arg \min_{ \boldsymbol{x}, \boldsymbol{z} } \quad & \underbrace{\frac{1}{2} \boldsymbol{x}^{T} \boldsymbol{A} \boldsymbol{x} }_{ f \left( \boldsymbol{x} \right) } + \underbrace{ 
{\pi}_{\mathcal{C}} \left( \boldsymbol{A} \boldsymbol{x} \right) }_{ g \left( \boldsymbol{z} \right) } \\
\text{subject to} \quad & \begin{aligned} 
\boldsymbol{A} \boldsymbol{x} - \boldsymbol{z} & = 0 \\
\end{aligned}
\end{align*}$$

Where ${\pi}_{\mathcal{C}} \left( \boldsymbol{x} \right)$ is the indicator function over the set $\mathcal{C} = {\left[ a, b \right]}^{m}$.

We have to define 2 steps, one per function:

- $ \arg \min_{\boldsymbol{x}} \frac{1}{2} \boldsymbol{x}^{T} \boldsymbol{A} \boldsymbol{x} + \frac{\lambda}{2} {\left\| \boldsymbol{A} \boldsymbol{x} - \boldsymbol{b} \right\|}_{2}^{2} $. Given the eigen decomposition of the operator $ \boldsymbol{A} = \boldsymbol{F} \boldsymbol{D} \boldsymbol{F}^{T} $ then $ \hat{\boldsymbol{x}} = \boldsymbol{F} \hat{\boldsymbol{D}} \boldsymbol{F}^{T} \boldsymbol{b} $ where $ \hat{{D}}_{ii} = \frac{ \lambda {D}_{ii} }{ \lambda {D}_{ii}^{2} + {D}_{ii} } = \frac{ \lambda }{ \lambda {D}_{ii} + 1 } $. This formulization allows updating $\lambda$ on the fly (Which can improve convergence).
- $ \operatorname{Prox}_{\lambda {\pi}_{\mathcal{C}} \left( \cdot \right)} \left( \boldsymbol{y} \right) = \operatorname{Proj}_{\mathcal{C}} \left( \boldsymbol{y} \right) = \max \left( \min \left( \boldsymbol{y}, b \right), a \right) $.

Using those *atoms* all needed is to keep iterating.
In case $\boldsymbol{A}$ is too large for decomposition (Sparse). one could use iterative solver to solve $ \left( \lambda \boldsymbol{A}^{T} \boldsymbol{A} + \boldsymbol{A} \right) \boldsymbol{x} = \lambda \boldsymbol{A}^{T} \boldsymbol{y} $.
It might be that even several iteration could be enough as the accuracy will get better with each ADMM iteration assuming using *warm up* technique.

#### PD3O Solution

The PD3O algorithm is relatively updated algorithm with guaranteed convergence for 3 operators split.
Its main advantage in this context is its ability to refrain from solving a linear system.

The model:

$$ \arg \min_{\boldsymbol{x}} \underbrace{\frac{1}{2} \boldsymbol{x}^{T} \boldsymbol{A} \boldsymbol{x} }_{ f \left( \boldsymbol{x} \right) } + \underbrace{0}_{g \left( \boldsymbol{x} \right)} + \underbrace{ 
{\pi}_{\mathcal{C}} \left( \boldsymbol{A} \boldsymbol{x} \right) }_{ h \left( \boldsymbol{A} \boldsymbol{x} \right) } $$

The building blocks needed are:

- For $ f \left( \cdot \right) $ its gradient $ {\nabla}_{\boldsymbol{x}} f $ is needed.
- For $ g \left( \cdot \right), \; h \left( \cdot \right) $ their proximal operator is needed.

Given that, the iterations are pretty simple.
Yet the algorithm is much slower than the ADMM above and is highly sensitive to the condition number of $ \boldsymbol{A} $.

**Remark**: Since this is a dual algorithm, it actually requires the proximal operator of the conjugate function of $ h \left( \cdot \right) $. Yet given the proximal of a function the proximal of its conjugate can be easily calculated as:

$$ \operatorname{Prox}_{ \lambda {h}^{\ast} \left( \cdot \right) } \left( \boldsymbol{y} \right) = \boldsymbol{y} - \lambda \operatorname{Prox}_{  \alpha h \left( \cdot \right) } \left( \alpha \boldsymbol{y} \right), \; \alpha = \frac{1}{\lambda} $$

#### Results

I implemented 3 algorithms for this problem (Chambolle Pock, which is a 2 operators Primal Dual method).

[image]

[image]

The `y` axis shows $ \frac{ \left| {f}^{\star} - {f}_{i} \right| }{ \left| {f}^{\star} \right| } $ in `dB`. Where $ {f}^{\star} $ is the optimal objective function value calculated by a Disciplined Convex Programming (DCP) solver.

The problem in both cases have the same dimensions, $ \boldsymbol{A} \in \mathbb{R}^{m \times n}, \; m = n = 500 $.
Yet the convergence speed is totally different from the primal dual methods while ADMM stays robust. The reason is the different condition number in the 2 cases.

Iteration wise, the work of the ADMM is much heavier, so the actual run time should measured.

The Julia code is available at my [StackExchange Mathematics Q3042354 GitHub Repository](https://github.com/RoyiAvital/StackExchangeCodes) (Look at the `Mathematics\Q3042354` folder).

**Remark**: Since Chambolle Pock is 2 operators Primal Dual method, it still requires solving the linear system. Hence ADMM is still preferred.

**Remark**: If $0 \in \left[ a, b \right]$ then the problem is solved by $0 \cdot \boldsymbol{1}$, namely the zero vector, as $ \boldsymbol{A} \in \mathcal{S}_{+}$. So basically $a. b$ must have the same sign.